# Extending dart:html class "ButtonElement" in Dart

Tags: html, dart, dart-polymer

I tried to extend a `<button>`, but so far did not succeed.
What am I doing wrong. I'm using the Dart Editor+SDK 1.5.2 
In pubspec.yaml the version for Polymer is set to:

```
polymer: ">=0.11.0 <0.12.0"
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
         not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Extended Button - Dart v1.5.2</title>

    <!--Extended Button-->     
    <link rel="import" href="view/ext_button.html" />                            

  </head>
  <body>

      <button is="ext-button">Test Button</button>                    

    <script type="application/dart">export "package:polymer/init.dart";</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**view/ext_button.dart**

```
import "dart:html";
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

@CustomTag("ext-button")
class ExtButton extends ButtonElement {    

  ExtButton.created() : super.created();

  factory ExtButton(){    
    onClick.listen(clicked);
  }

  void clicked(MouseEvent e){
    print("Ext-Button clicked");
  }
}
```

**view/ext_button.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="ext-button" extends="button">
  <template>    
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="ext_button.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

So the code above does not work, but as soon as write it like below (just to validate the ext-button works) it tells me the following:
*"web/index.html:20:7: custom element "ext-button" extends from "button", but this tag will not include the default properties of "button". 
To fix this, either write this tag as `<button is="ext-button">` or remove the "extends" attribute from the custom element declaration."*

```
<ext-button>Test Button</ext-button>
```

So a little bit confused ;-) I think the fix is easy and simple - but I just don't see the problem ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, you are missing thwo things:

- a call to `polymerCreated()` inside the custom elements constructor.
- and `extends ButtonElement with Polymer`

There are already similar question. I'll look them up later when I have more time. Maybe you find them yourself in the meantime. Please add a comment with a link if you do.

Answer (score 2):

Just for further references, the two things above solved the problem.
Here are the updated parts, now it works.

**view/ext_button.dart**

```
import "dart:html";
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

@CustomTag("ext-button")
class ExtButton extends ButtonElement with Polymer {    

  ExtButton.created() : super.created()
  {
     polymerCreated();
     onClick.listen(clicked);
  }

  void clicked(MouseEvent e){
    print("Ext-Button clicked");
  }
}
```

**view/ext_button.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="ext-button" extends="button">
  <template> 
<content></content>   
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="ext_button.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```